# Young adult novel involving Time-travel, via a round, rainbow like portal

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult, lester-del-rey

Haven't read it since I was a child, but I recall a story involving a young man whose father built some kind of time portal that appeared as a circular rainbow. ("No end, therefore no pot of gold" was mentioned at one point.)

During the story, I believe they move through it at least once or twice in its early, dinosaur era incarnation, and at one point have it suffer major issues when a dinosaur steps on it, and a tube-shaped volume of Dino comes through it.

Later, it's pointed at a later (historically) time, where the protagonist befriends a young girl (and makes her some clothing, which she later takes off, points at him and puts back on, to his embarrassment, as she tries to explain where it came from) who, at the end of the story, inadvertently came back with them to the 'modern' age.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, the duplicate is the other way around; mine was posted (and answered) six years ago.

Comment: That's not how our duplicate policy works. The answer on the other post is better than the one here and includes more details.

Comment: Per [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4744/70236), quality is more important than age when closing as duplicates. This is in line with the whole point of the duplicate system, which aims at pointing people at better questions and answers.

Comment: Perhaps, but the reality is that the new question should have been closed, pointing at this one; it's timing only that allows the new one to be kept because of a 'better' answer.  This policy really needs revisited, I would suggest.

Comment: Actually the newer one couldn't be closed as a duplicate UNTIL it had the same answer, as per our [story-id dupe policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/). These two policies are what's best for the site, unfortunately this means your question should be closed

Comment: @K-H-W it's certainly possible that our policy needs to be revisited; that's what [meta](http://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com) is for.

Comment: @KutuluMike- Oh, I 'm well aware -- I'm currently discussing it on Meta :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The book you are looking for is [Tunnel Through Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_Through_Time), a 1966 novel by [Lester Del Rey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lester_Del_Rey).

Comment: Bingo!  That's the one; thank you VERY much!

Comment: @Keith: You're quite welcome. :)