# Seeking book from elementary school, with dinosaurs and probably time travel

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, childrens-novel

When I was in fourth grade, in the mid-1980s, my advanced reading class finished the regular textbook several weeks early, so our teacher selected a novel for us to read.  I only saw the cover though, which featured a [Kirby-boom-tube-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boom_tube) tunnel with a human figure inside it.  The tunnel was probably a time travel device, since the terrain surrounding the visible end of the tube was filled with jungles and dinosaurs.

I never got to read the book, because a creationist parent complained, and the teacher selected a different, non-SF book for the class.  Any idea what this was?

Comment: Mid 1908's or 1980's?

Comment: @dean1957 Whoops!

Comment: @Buzz- no problem just making sure I have done typo's before too. LOL

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166298/time-travel-book-featuring-dinosaurs-cave-people-and-children

Answer (score 7):

Possibly "[Tunnel through Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_Through_Time)" (1966) under the byline of Lester Del Rey. I remember reading it (or something similar with a brontosaurus getting fried by the time ring) in the '70s.

Here's a cover showing the boom-tube like image, but lacking the jungle and dinosaur view at the far end.

[image: Stylized cover of time tunnel]
Also:
[image: Dinosaur-laden cover]

And for completeness, unlikely second option: some version of [The Time Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Tunnel)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Previous questions have had this book as an answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166298/time-travel-book-featuring-dinosaurs-cave-people-and-children

Comment: I'm sure that I've see that cover illustration before, but I'm also pretty confident the book I'm thinking of showed dinosaurs.  I may be combining two different book covers in my mind.  Or there might be additional illustrations on the back cover.

Comment: The Time Tunnel was also a TV series. The black and white inset picture is a still from it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Tunnel

Answer (score 1):

Off chance here, but possibly Heinlein's Tunnel in the Sky. No dinosaurs but the covers tend to show a guy going through a portal of some sort, and in the version I've posted below, it somewhat resembles the Boom-Tube. It's also one of Heinlein's juvinovels, which would also make sense for a fourth grade class. There is some death, violence, and teens working out relationships in order to overcome natural obstacles. Think Lord of the Flies where the main characters decide to remember that they carried their civilization with them, so to speak. I can definitely see a certain kind of parent complaining about it.

[image: Tunnel in the Sky cover]